# Multiple conditions when contains(@attribute) in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

For example, if I want to find **link** tag with **application type** **"application/javascript"** or **"application/ecmascript"**, I would like to do something like this:

```
response.xpath("head/link[contains(@type, "javascript", "ecmascript")]")
```

It goes without saying that the code I putted above will raise an exception.

But I haven't found the way which will help me to apply multiple conditions in one XPath query.

Comment: In XPath 2.0 you can use `[@type=("application/javascript", "application/ecmascript")]` predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.xpath("head/link[@type[contains(., 'javascript') or contains(., 'ecmascript')]]")
```

Be careful not using the same quotes in code and XPath.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I did a mistake when I was writing my question ) Thank you once again.